# How To clear asp:ListView Rows binded by sqlDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem in clearing listView when click on clear button list view in binded by sqlDataReader and i want to clear list view on clear button
Below i am attaching my code

```
if (Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"] != null)
                {
                    if (Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("btncheck"))
                    {
                        string[] arg = Page.Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString().Split(',');
                        lsvSearchResult.DataSource = null;
                        lsvSearchResult.DataBind();
                        if (Convert.ToString(arg[0]) == "IDNO")
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToString(arg[1]).Trim() != "")
                            { 
                                lsvSearchResult.DataSource = GetStudents(arg[0], arg[1]);
                                lsvSearchResult.DataBind();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (Convert.ToString(arg[0]) == "NAME")
                        {
                            lsvSearchResult.DataSource = GetStudents(arg[0], arg[1]);
                            lsvSearchResult.DataBind();
                        }
                    }

                    //GetStudents(arg[0], arg[1]);
                }
                else if (Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("btncancemodal"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        txtSearch.Text = string.Empty;
                        //lsvSearchResult.Items.Clear();
                        DataSet ds = null;
                        lsvSearchResult.DataSource = ds;
                        lsvSearchResult.DataBind();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // error
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: -1 you cant just throw code like that

Answer (score 0):

**how about:**

```
DataSource = null; 

DataBind();
```

**or:**

```
lsvSearchResult.DataSource = null;

lsvSearchResult.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

if (Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"] != null)
                {
                    if (Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("btncheck"))
                    {
                        string[] arg = Page.Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString().Split(',');
                        lsvSearchResult.DataSource = null;
                        lsvSearchResult.DataBind();
                        if (Convert.ToString(arg[0]) == "IDNO")
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToString(arg[1]).Trim() != "")
                            { 
                                lsvSearchResult.DataSource = GetStudents(arg[0], arg[1]);
                                lsvSearchResult.DataBind();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (Convert.ToString(arg[0]) == "NAME")
                        {
                            lsvSearchResult.DataSource = GetStudents(arg[0], arg[1]);
                            lsvSearchResult.DataBind();
                        }
                    }

```
                //GetStudents(arg[0], arg[1]);
            }
            else if (Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("btncancemodal"))
            {
                try
                {
                    txtSearch.Text = string.Empty;
                    //lsvSearchResult.Items.Clear();
                    DataSet ds = null;
                    lsvSearchResult.DataSource = ds;
                    lsvSearchResult.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // error
                }
            }
        }
```

I Have placed If curly bracket in wrong position.
any ways thanks for your comments